# Putting an array (Javascript) into PostgreSQL in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, arrays, postgresql

- Table (Person) created with column (Items) that has a Array Type.
- I'm using Angular 1.6 + Rails 5 + Postgresql

Schema looks like:

```
create_table "Person", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "items",       default: [],              array: true
```

Javascript looks like:

```
person.items = ['A','B']
```

When I try putting it in the DB, all other variables (type string/integers) get stored but not this Array Type. 
Is there a format that I do not know about? Please help!

Comment: It may be helpful if you show your `params.require().permit()` bit of code. Also, your console log during the attempted transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered the string values like "{A,B}". When I pull from the database I get ["A","B"].